# R merge data.frames asof join

Tags: r, join, dataframe

I have a whole bunch of data.frames with irregular time spacing.

I would like to make a new data.frame and join the others to it, for each data.frame being joined picking the latest value out of the new data.frame.

For example, listOfDataFrames below contains a list of data.frames each of which has a time column in seconds. I find the total range, mod the range by 60 and seqn it by to obtain an increasing seqn of full minutes. Now I need to merge the list of data.frames to the left of this new seqn. e.g. if the value in mypoints is 60, the value joined to it should be the latest value <= 60.

```
xrange <- range(lapply(listOfDataFrames,function(x) range(x$Time)))
mypoints <- 60*do.call(seq,as.list(xrange%/%60))
```

I believe this is sometimes called an asof join.

Is there a simple procedure to do this?

Thanks

EDIT: this is what I currently use

```
xrange <- range(lapply(listOfDataFrames,function(x) range(x$Time)))
mypoints <- 60*seq(xrange[1]%/%60,1+xrange[2]%/%60)
result <- data.frame(Time=mypoints)
for(index in 1:length(listOfDataFrames))
{
  x<-listOfDataFrames[[index]]
  indices <- which(sort(c(mypoints,x$Time)) %in% mypoints) - 1:length(mypoints)
  indices[indices==0] <- NA
  newdf<-data.frame(new=x$Result[indices])
  colnames(newdf)<-paste("S",index,sep="")
  result <- cbind(result,newdf)
}
```

EDIT: full example

```
AsOfJoin <- function (listOfDataFrames) {
  xrange <- range(lapply(listOfDataFrames,function(x) range(x$Time)))
  mypoints <- 60*seq(xrange[1]%/%60,1+xrange[2]%/%60)
  result <- data.frame(Time=mypoints)
  for(index in 1:length(listOfDataFrames))
  {
    x<-listOfDataFrames[[index]]
    indices <- which(sort(c(mypoints,x$Time)) %in% mypoints) - 1:length(mypoints)
    indices[indices==0] <- NA
    newdf<-data.frame(new=x$Result[indices])
    colnames(newdf)<-paste("S",index,sep="")
    result <- cbind(result,newdf)
  }
  result[is.na(result)]<-0
  result
}


a<-data.frame(Time=c(28947.5,28949.6,29000),Result=c(10,15,9))
b<-data.frame(Time=c(28947.8,28949.5),Result=c(14,19))
listOfDataFrames <- list(a,b)
result<-AsOfJoin(listOfDataFrames)

    > a
         Time Result
    1 28947.5     10
    2 28949.6     15
    3 29000.0      9
    > b
         Time Result
    1 28947.8     14
    2 28949.5     19
    > result
       Time S1 S2
    1 28920  0  0
    2 28980 15 19
    3 29040  9 19
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example, perhaps a list of 2-3 data frames that illustrate your problem? Also, what do you intend should happen if there isn't a *unique* latest value <= 60?

Comment: The lists should all be sorted. Just imagine maybe the number of patients in a waiting room, and them randomly arriving every possible second. We want to know how many people are waiting every full minute, and then join that for e.g. 5 weekdays.

Comment: You're not increasing the odds of someone helping by asking them to "imagine" some data.  Help us help you.

Comment: I played with this for a bit, but every solution I thought of ended up being of the same general length and complexity. Perhaps someone else will have more luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my edit for answer. Apparently the best way.

Answer (score 1):

[data.table](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) provide very fast `asof` joins out of the box.
See also [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076065/data-table-inner-outer-join-with-na-in-join-column-of-type-double-bug/14276100#14276100) for an example