# How does one do a full join using data.table?

Tags: r, join, data.table, outer-join

In the [`data.table` FAQ](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/datatable-faq.pdf), the `nomatch = NA` parameter is said to be akin to an outer join. However, I haven't been able to get `data.table` to do a *full* outer join – only right outer joins.

For example:

```
a <- data.table("dog" = c(8:12), "cat" = c(15:19))

   dog cat
1:   8  15
2:   9  16
3:  10  17
4:  11  18
5:  12  19

b <- data.table("dog" = 1:10, "bullfrog" = 11:20)

    dog bullfrog
 1:   1       11
 2:   2       12
 3:   3       13
 4:   4       14
 5:   5       15
 6:   6       16
 7:   7       17
 8:   8       18
 9:   9       19
10:  10       20

setkey(a, dog)
setkey(b, dog)

a[b, nomatch = NA]

    dog cat bullfrog
 1:   1  NA       11
 2:   2  NA       12
 3:   3  NA       13
 4:   4  NA       14
 5:   5  NA       15
 6:   6  NA       16
 7:   7  NA       17
 8:   8  15       18
 9:   9  16       19
10:  10  17       20
```

So, `nomatch = NA` produces a right outer join (which is the default). What if I need a full join? For example:

```
merge(a, b, by = "dog", all = TRUE) 
# Or with plyr:
join(a, b, by = "dog", type = "full")

    dog cat bullfrog
 1:   1  NA       11
 2:   2  NA       12
 3:   3  NA       13
 4:   4  NA       14
 5:   5  NA       15
 6:   6  NA       16
 7:   7  NA       17
 8:   8  15       18
 9:   9  16       19
10:  10  17       20
11:  11  18       NA
12:  12  19       NA
```

Is that possible with `data.table`?

Comment: For joins with data.table see last answer of [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076065/data-table-inner-outer-join-with-na-in-join-column-of-type-double-bug?rq=1

Comment: For all sorts of joins with data.table see last answer of [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076065/data-table-inner-outer-join-with-na-in-join-column-of-type-double-bug?rq=1

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You actually have it right there.  Use  `merge.data.table` which is exactly what you are doing when you call

```
merge(a, b, by = "dog", all = TRUE)
```

since `a` is a `data.table`,  `merge(a, b, ...)` calls `merge.data.table(a, b, ...)`

Comment: Is there any way we can achieve the same result with the `A[B]` syntax?

Answer (score 13):

```
x= data.table(a=1:5,b=11:15)
y= data.table(a=c(1:4,6),c=c(101:104,106))

setkey(x,a)
setkey(y,a)

unique_keys <- unique(c(x[,a], y[,a]))
y[x[.(unique_keys), on="a"]  ] # Full Outer Join
```

Comment: Brilliant! To make it easier to understand, I'd like to break the last two lines to three: 1) `unique_keys <- data.table(a = unique(c(x[,a], y[,a])))` 2)
`xx <- x[unique_keys]` 3) `y[xx]`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach to getting a full join would be to read the full join as a right join plus an anti join:

```
rbind(
  fill = TRUE,
  a[b, on = ...],
  a[!b, on = ...]
)
```