# Copy only one variable from one R data.table to another after matching on a variable

Tags: r, data.table

I can conduct a matched copy of a column in a data frame into another by something like

```r
DF2$y <- DF1[match(DF2$id2, DF1$id1), "z"]  # DF1 and DF2 are data frames
```

where `DF2$id2` is matched to `DF1$id1`. I would like to know what I can do with **data tables** for this kind of operation. My data tables have millions of rows and hundreds of columns. I've done `setkey(DT1, id1)` and `setkey(DT2, id2)`.

This works:

```r
DT2[, y := DT1[match(DT2$id2, DT1$id1), "z"]]  # DT1 and DT2 are data tables
```

but I am afraid that the `match` part might take long than necessary. (Or is it inevitable?)

I understand that I can also use column selection, `merge`, and renaming:

```r
tmp <- DT1[, c("id1", "z")]  # column selection
DT3 <- merge(DT2, tmp, by.x = "id2", by.y = "id1", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("", ".y")) # merge
setnames(DT3, "z.y", "y")  # rename
```

(where the first two lines can be written on one line) but this seems a bit too complicated. Would there be a simpler and fast solution?

Thanks.

Example:

```r
library(data.table)
DF1 <- data.frame(id1=2:4, x=LETTERS[1:3], z=11:13)
DF2 <- data.frame(id2=1:4, x=LETTERS[5:8], z=21:24)
DF1
#   id1 x  z
# 1   2 A 11
# 2   3 B 12
# 3   4 C 13
DF2
#   id2 x  z
# 1   1 E 21
# 2   2 F 22
# 3   3 G 23
# 4   4 H 24

DT1 <- data.table(DF1)
DT2 <- data.table(DF2)
setkey(DT1, id1)
setkey(DT2, id2)

DF2$y <- DF1[match(DF2$id2, DF1$id1), "z"]
DF2  # correct
#   id2 x  z  y
# 1   1 E 21 NA
# 2   2 F 22 11
# 3   3 G 23 12
# 4   4 H 24 13

DT2[, y := DT1[match(DT2$id2, DT1$id1), "z"]]
DT2
#    id2 x  z  y
# 1:   1 E 21 NA
# 2:   2 F 22 11
# 3:   3 G 23 12
# 4:   4 H 24 13
DT2[, y := NULL]

tmp <- DT1[, c("id1", "z")]
DT3 <- merge(DT2, tmp, by.x = "id2", by.y = "id1", all.x = TRUE, suffixes = c("", ".y"))
setnames(DT3, "z.y", "y")
DT3
#    id2 x  z  y
# 1:   1 E 21 NA
# 2:   2 F 22 11
# 3:   3 G 23 12
# 4:   4 H 24 13

## Simpler alternatives?
```

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks. But I want to "merge" only one variable, not the full data set. For this I need to do column selection, merging, and then renaming as I explained in the question. Are there simpler ways?

Comment: `merge` is the simple. It's annoying about this particular example that the names of your ID columns don't match, and the name of the column you want to add needs to change, but renaming is a one-liner that is very efficient.

Comment: And I would agree with your worry - I would expect `data.table::merge` to be much faster than `base::match`, especially on keyed tables. But I disagree with your assessment that renaming a couple columns is too complicated.

Comment: Or a little more simply, `merge(DT2, setnames(DT1[, c("id1", "z")], c("id2", "y")), all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: @GregorThomas Sure. Thanks. I wondered if there are other solutions, and I am glad to learn I need not look for other solutions. I've been wandering around with this issue so long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to append column `z` from `DT1` to `DT2` as column `y` where the id columns match.

With [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table), this can be solved using an *update join*:

```
library(data.table)
DT2[DT1, on = .(id2 = id1), y := i.z]
DT2
```

> ```
>    id2 x  z  y
> 1:   1 E 21 NA
> 2:   2 F 22 11
> 3:   3 G 23 12
> 4:   4 H 24 13
> ```

Note that `DT2` is updated *by reference*, i.e., without copying the whole data object. This might be handy for OP's large production datasets of millions of rows.

#### Caveat

This works because `id1` and `id2` are *unique* which is the case for the sample use case. So, make sure that you get what you want when you do *update joins* on duplicate values.

Let's see what will happen if there are duplicate values in the `id1` column, e.g.

In case `DT1` has `id1 == 4` duplicated

```
(DT1 <- data.table(id1 = c(2:4, 4), x = LETTERS[1:4], z = 11:14))
```

> ```
>    id1 x  z
> 1:   2 A 11
> 2:   3 B 12
> 3:   4 C 13
> 4:   4 D 14
> ```

then

```
DT2[DT1, on = .(id2 = id1), y := i.z][]
```

returns

> ```
>    id2 x  z  y
> 1:   1 E 21 NA
> 2:   2 F 22 11
> 3:   3 G 23 12
> 4:   4 H 24 14
> ```

So, the *update join*

- has not created additional rows in `DT2` (which is probably what you may want to avoid copying of large datasets),
- has picked the last occurrence of `z` in case of multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

I have two possible ideas:

1. Using `merge` and select the columns and do the renaming there

```
DT3 <- merge(DT2, DT1[, .(id1, y = z)], by.x = "id2", by.y = "id1", all.x = TRUE)
```

2. Using `data.table`'s `on` syntax. I based this solution directly off of the answer here, which shows how to do a full outer join:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904676/9244371

```
unique_keys <- unique(c(DT1[, id1], DT2[, id2]))
DT3 <- DT2[DT1[.(unique_keys), .(id1, y = z)]]
```