# merge.data.table with all=True introduces NA row. Is this correct?

Tags: r, data.table, outer-join

Doing a merge between a populated data.table and another one that is empty introduces one NA row in the resulting data.table:

```
a = data.table(c=c(1,2),key='c')
b = data.table(c=3,key='c')
b=b[c!=3]
b
# Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: c
merge(a,b,all=T)
#     c
# 1: NA
# 2:  1
# 3:  2
```

Why? I expected that it would return only the rows of data.table `a`, as it does with merge.data.frame:

```
> merge.data.frame(a,b,all=T,by='c')
#  c
#1 1
#2 2
```

Comment: So you want to merge `a` with an empty data table `b`. Why you introduce `b` in such unusual way? Why not to use `b=data.table()` ?

Comment: @user974514: I just wanted to reproduce the problem as it appeared in my code. Generally the `data.table`'s in my code are populated, but sometimes not, and in my case the tables are keyed and the merge naturally uses these keys. A simple `data.table()` does not reproduce exactly the problem I had.

Comment: @user974514, that would give a NULL data.table (0 rows and columns) and there will be no "key" column. So, merge would not be possible.

Comment: @Arun, I don't think so. I did the same thing with a `data.frame` and the result was the expected one: a new `data.frame` with just the rows of the populated one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The example in the question is far too simple to show the problem, hence the confusion and discussion. Using two one-column `data.table`s isn't enough to show what `merge` does!

Here's a better example :

```
> a = data.table(P=1:2,Q=3:4,key='P')
> b = data.table(P=2:3,R=5:6,key='P')
> a
   P Q
1: 1 3
2: 2 4
> b
   P R
1: 2 5
2: 3 6
> merge(a,b)  # correct
   P Q R
1: 2 4 5
> merge(a,b,all=TRUE)  # correct.  
   P  Q  R
1: 1  3 NA
2: 2  4  5
3: 3 NA  6
> merge(a,b[0],all=TRUE)  # incorrect result when y is empty, agreed
    P  Q  R
1: NA NA NA
2: NA NA NA
3:  1  3 NA
4:  2  4 NA
> merge.data.frame(a,b[0],all=TRUE)  # correct
  P Q  R
1 1 3 NA
2 2 4 NA
```

Ricardo got to the bottom of this and fixed it in v1.8.9. From NEWS :

> merge no longer returns spurious NA row(s) when y is empty and
>   all.y=TRUE (or all=TRUE), [#2633](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=240&aid=2633&atid=975). Thanks
>   to Vinicius Almendra for reporting. Test added.

Answer (score 2):

> > all : logical; all = TRUE is shorthand to save setting both all.x = TRUE and all.y = TRUE.
> >
> > all.x :     logical; if TRUE, then extra rows will be added to the output, one for each row in
> >             x that has no matching row in y. These rows ***will have ’NA’s in those columns***
> >             that are usually ﬁlled with values from y. The default is FALSE, so that only rows
> >             with data from both x and y are included in the output.
> >
> > all.y : logical; analogous to all.x above.

This is taken from **[data.table documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf)**. For more, look at the description of the arguments for `merge` function there.

I think this answers your question.

Comment: maybe you could try `ifelse(dim(b)[1]==0, merge(a,b,all.x=T), merge(a,b,all.y=T))` or something similar

Comment: This documentation is the same as of `merge.data.frame`, which behaves differently. I don't understand why a full outer join with an empty table should add an NA row.

Answer (score 0):

Given you define `a` and `b` in your way. The simple usage of `rbind(a,b)` would return only the rows of `a`.

However if you want to merge NULL data table `b` with some other non-empty data table `a`, there's different approach. I had similar problem when I had to merge different data tables within different loops. I used this workaround.

```
  #some loop that returns data.table named a
  #another loop starts
  if(all.equal(a,b<-data.table())==TRUE){
  b<-a
  next
  }
  merge(a,b,c("Factor1","Factor2"))
```

That helped me, maybe it will help you too.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get your if-statement. If `a` is a `data.table` of dimensions `0 by 0` (like `b`), then you assign `b` to `a`. Why? And you are not using `copy(a)`. This'll just assign by reference and not copy a to b. I don't get it.

Comment: Suppose you have a loop where you fill data.table `a`. So it's not empty. But at the end of the loop you want to merge it with other data table `b` which can be empty in first iteration, but becomes non-empty in second. That's what this workaround solve.

Comment: The down vote is from me, if you could explain (or edit), I'd be happy to up-vote).

Comment: thanks for the reply. it makes sense now. but it doesn't answer the OP's question, as the data.table is **not** of 0 rows **and columns**, but just 0 rows **and 1 column**.

Comment: For OP's question, I recommended to use `rbind(a,b)`. The output will be only `a` rows just as OP demanded.

Comment: @user97, thanks. `rbind` is not a solution, since it assumes both tables have the same columns. That exactly the reason for using `merge ` instead of rbind.

Answer (score 0):

That's to be expected, as for `merge.data.frame` `all=T` is a `full outer join`, so you get all keys of both tables see [about merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076065/data-table-inner-outer-join-with-na-in-join-column-of-type-double-bug)

Comment: Table `b` has an empty key (no rows), which is different from a key with value NA.

Comment: You might have found a bug, as this is a very unusual case, can you post on data-table list ?

Comment: Thanks. I have just submitted it and another bug I found, also related to empty data.table's...

Comment: table b does *not* have an empty key. `tables()` shows that the key is set to column `c`.

Comment: not sure why we still speak about it, `data.table` should replicate data.frame behaviour, it's a bug let's close ad move on...