# More efficient rolling join backwards not forwards?

Tags: r, join, data.table

`data.table` implements `asof` (also know as `rolling` or `LOCF`) joins out of the box. I've found this related question :

[Filling in missing (blanks) in a data table, per category - backwards and forwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607465/filling-in-missing-blanks-in-a-data-table-per-category-backwards-and-forwar)

but that question has NAs in the data. In my case I'm following the advice there to keep the data irregular and join to it using `roll=TRUE`. What I'd like to do instead of the last observation carried forward, is the next observation to be carried backward, as efficiently as possible.

This is what I've tried, using `time:=-time` first to try and trick it. Can I do it better? Can I do it faster?

```
llorJoin <- function(A,B){
    B <- copy(B);
    keys <- key(A);
    if( !identical(key(A), key(B)) | is.null(keys) ){
       stop("llorJoin::ERROR; A and B should have the same non-empty keys");
    }

    lastKey <- tail(keys,1L);
    myStr <- parse(text=paste0(lastKey,":=-as.numeric(",lastKey,")"));
    A <- A[,eval(myStr)]; setkeyv(A,keys);
    B <- B[,eval(myStr)]; setkeyv(B,keys);

    origin <- "1970-01-01 00:00.00 UTC";
    A <- B[A,roll=T];
    myStr2 <- parse(text=paste0(lastKey,":=as.POSIXct(-",lastKey,",origin=origin)"));
    A <- A[,eval(myStr2)]; setkeyv(A,keys);
    return(A);
}
```

---

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(time=as.POSIXct(c("10:01:01","10:01:02","10:01:04","10:01:05","10:01:02","10:01:01","10:01:01"),format="%H:%M:%S"),
                b=c("a","a","a","a","b","c","c"),
                d=c(1,1.9,2,1.8,5,4.1,4.2));
B <- data.table(time=as.POSIXct(c("10:01:01","10:01:03","10:01:00","10:01:01"),format="%H:%M:%S"),b=c("a","a","c","d"), e=c(1L,2L,3L,4L));
setkey(A,b,time)
setkey(B,b,time)
```

---

```
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(llorJoin(A,B),B[A,roll=T],replications=10)
            test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1 llorJoin(A, B)           10   0.045        1     0.048        0          0         0
2 B[A, roll = T]           10   0.009        1     0.008        0          0         0

   b                time  e   d
1: a 2013-01-12 09:01:01  1 1.0
2: a 2013-01-12 09:01:02  2 1.9
3: a 2013-01-12 09:01:04 NA 2.0
4: a 2013-01-12 09:01:05 NA 1.8
5: b 2013-01-12 09:01:02 NA 5.0
6: c 2013-01-12 09:01:01 NA 4.1
7: c 2013-01-12 09:01:01 NA 4.2
```

So as a comparaison, asof join on the initial data is 5X faster.

Comment: What specifically is your question? You say you want a last observation carried backward instead of `locf` but you already have an implementation. Does it work? Is it too slow? Are you looking for something more idiomatic? I know nothing about `data.table` package so I cannot help anyway, but with your question in its current form, those potential answerers who **do** use `data.table` are likely as confused as I am.

Comment: The problem is that to do `B[A,roll=T]`, `A` and `B` have to be sorted. Then reversing `time:=-time` breaks the sort. I tried to gain time in removing the `setkey` sortings afterwards doing the sort "myself" by `A[,time:=time[.N:.1],by="b"]` and using `setattr(A,c("b","time"))`, but it seems longer...

Comment: @statquant The point of StackOverflow is to ask clear questions that generate useful answers, so that others can benefit. I have looked through your questions and you do have a tendency to be verbose; this is not a problem of English but a problem of mental organisation. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585820/r-merge-data-frames-asof-join) ended up as a decent question and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076065/data-table-inner-outer-join-with-na-in-join-column-of-type-double-bug) found a bug. So it's useful stuff, but please remember that concision is important!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`roll` argument can perform *nocb* since a long time ago. Updating this answer so that [#615](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/615) can be closed.

You don't need to set keys anymore as well. Instead you can specify the columns to join on using `on=` argument (implemented in `v1.9.6`). With these two features, the task can be accomplished as follows:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.6+
A[B, on=c("b", "time"), roll=-Inf]
#                   time b  e   d
# 1: 2015-10-11 10:01:01 a  1 1.0
# 2: 2015-10-11 10:01:02 a  2 1.9
# 3: 2015-10-11 10:01:04 a NA 2.0
# 4: 2015-10-11 10:01:05 a NA 1.8
# 5: 2015-10-11 10:01:02 b NA 5.0
# 6: 2015-10-11 10:01:01 c NA 4.1
# 7: 2015-10-11 10:01:01 c NA 4.2
```

That's it.

---

You're pretty close to the fastest way without a change to `data.table`. The following feature request has been filed some time ago :

[FR#2300 Add backwards and firstback to roll=TRUE](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/615)

I've added a link there back to this question. You can search the feature request list on R-Forge. In this case words like "roll", "forwards" and "backwards" all find it. You might need 4 or 5 attempts search attempts to confirm the bug or feature request isn't already filed.

It's probably quicker for me to implement that feature request (only a few lines internally are needed) than try and provide you the quickest possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, are you upgrading the priority of the feature request or leave it as it is? Can I suggest to change `roll=T` to `roll={"locf","nocb"}` (next observation carried backward)

Comment: There was an idea somewhere for `roll=-30` (next observation provided not more than diff of 30, likely days), `roll=+30` (locf provided it was within 30 days ago). So the current `TRUE` would correspond to `+Inf`. and `FALSE` to `0`. `-Inf` would be nocb. What you think?

Comment: I think it's brilliant, it's adding the additional feature of "window" joining !