# window (aka rolling) join with data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I am trying to find a way around this request feature : [[#2300] Add backwards and firstback to roll=TRUE](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=2300) which was mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293791/more-efficient-rolling-join-backwards-not-forwards).

Basically I would like to perform the following "window-join" of `X` looking up in `Y`

1. left join on the first n columns (in the following example `{x,y}`)
2. AND select values of a last column (`t` in following example) in `Y` that falls into the `[t-w1,t+w2]` interval where t is the last column in `X`, typically `t` would be a time column and `{w1,w2}` some integers (likely `w1=w2=something` or `w1=0`)

I built the following example (but feel free to provide another/better one)

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123);
X <- data.table(x=c(1,1,1,2,2),y=c(T,T,F,F,F),t=as.POSIXct("08:00:00.000",format="%H:%M:%OS")+sample(0:999,5,TRUE)/1e3)
Y <- copy(X)
set.seed(123)
Y[,`:=`(IDX=.I,t=t+sample(c(-5:5)/1e3,5,T))]
Y <- rbindlist(list(Y, X[5,][,IDX:=6][,t:=t+0.001], X[5,][,IDX:=7][,t:=t+0.002]))
```

So with `(w1,w2) = (.002,.002)`

```
R) X                                 R) Y
   x     y                       t      x     y                       t IDX
1: 1  TRUE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.286   1: 1  TRUE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.284   1
2: 1  TRUE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.788   2: 1  TRUE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.791   2
3: 1 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.407   3: 1 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.407   3
4: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.882   4: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.886   4
5: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.940   5: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.945   5
                                     6: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.941   6 #by hand
                                     7: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.942   7 #by hand
```

The result would be

```
R) ans
   x     y                       t IDX
1: 1  TRUE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.286   1
2: 1  TRUE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.788  NA
3: 1 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.407   3
4: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.882  NA
5: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.940  6,7
```

But: `IDX` here could very well be a list if several rows of `Y` (which can have more rows than `X`) matched, one just one, or `NA` if none matched.

I would be happy with some non-data.table answers too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a try, not very elegant, without `data.table` but with `plyr`. Don't know if it could be useful to you.

Sample data :

```
X <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2),y=c(T,T,F,F,F),t=rep(1,5)+sample(0:999,5,TRUE)/1e3)
Y <- data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2),y=c(T,T,F,F,F),t=rep(1,5)+sample(0:999,5,TRUE)/1e3, IDX=1:5)
w1 <- 0.3
w2 <- 0.3
```

Which gives :

```
R> X
  x     y     t
1 1  TRUE 1.880
2 1  TRUE 1.364
3 1 FALSE 1.288
4 2 FALSE 1.170
5 2 FALSE 1.172
R> Y
  x     y     t IDX
1 1  TRUE 1.482   1
2 1  TRUE 1.252   2
3 1 FALSE 1.216   3
4 2 FALSE 1.674   4
5 2 FALSE 1.047   5
```

Then you can use the following code :

```
m <- merge(X,Y, by=c("x","y"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
m <- m[m$t.x>m$t.y-w1 & m$t.x<m$t.y+w2,]
m <- ddply(m, c("x","y","t.x"), summarize, IDX=list(IDX))
names(m) <- c("x","y","t","IDX")
merge(X, m, by=c("x","y","t"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE)
```

Which gives the following result :

```
  x     y     t  IDX
1 1 FALSE 1.288    3
2 1  TRUE 1.364 1, 2
3 1  TRUE 1.880   NA
4 2 FALSE 1.170    5
5 2 FALSE 1.172    5
```

Comment: Good stuff!, I am getting the expected answer with `m <- m[m$t.x>=(m$t.y-w1) & m$t.x<=(m$t.y+w2),]`. Thanks, I'll wait a bit for a `data.table` answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is a translation of juba's code in `data.table` (v.1.8.7 r797)

```
setkey(X,x,y,t); setkey(Y,x,y,t)
m <- merge(X,Y, by=c("x","y"), all.x=TRUE, all.y=FALSE, allow.cartesian=TRUE)
m <- m[t.x>=(t.y-w1) & t.x<=(t.y+w2)]
m <- m[, list(IDX=list(IDX)), by=c("x","y","t.x")];
setnames(m,"t.x","t");
m <- m[X];
```

I get this (note the `NULL`, Matthew Dowle might explain why we get this instead of `NA`)

```
R) m
   x     y                       t IDX
1: 1 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.407   3
2: 1  TRUE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.286   1
3: 1  TRUE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.788
4: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.882
5: 2 FALSE 2013-01-25 08:00:00.940 6,7
```

I'll wait for an expert to say if it is a `data.table-optimal` solution to close the post.

Comment: You get `NULL` because you're looking up `c(1,2,NA,NA,3)` in a list (`IDX`).  Compare `integer(3)[c(1,2,NA,NA,3)]` and `as.list(integer(3))[c(1,2,NA,NA,3)]`.